# Parsing a Data Table from Website That is Using JSON

Tags: json, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to parse data from the Minnesota DNR page and it says they are using JSON.  I want to build a script to download the data tables from many different pages but am focusing on one first.  I have tried rvest, JSONIO, and many other packages to no avail.  The most frustrating error I am getting is:

> Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") : 
>     no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "list"

Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)

kk<-read_html("http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/lakefind/showreport.html?downum=56003100")

node <- "table.table_colors:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1)"

html_table(node, fill=TRUE)

head(kk)
```

How do I get this table to download with the headers in tact???

Comment: I think `node` should be something returned from `html_node()`, not a literal character string of the search string.

Comment: BTW, your code gives me a different error, instead complaining `... applied to an object of class 'character'`. Is there any relevant code you're omitting?

Comment: I think I did copy in an older version of the code.  I tried a lot of different approaches to try and fix that! I now get the same error you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the actual data that goes into making the table. It's JSON and not too complex:

```
library(httr)

res <- GET("http://maps2.dnr.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/lakefinder/detail.cgi", 
           query=list(type="lake_survey", id="56003100"))

str(content(res))
```

This lets you get metadata by county name:

```
get_lake_metadata <- function(county_name) {

  require(httr)
  require(dplyr)
  require(jsonlite)

  xlate_df <- data_frame(
    id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
           11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
           24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
           37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 43L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
           50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
           63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 69L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
           76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L), 
    county = c("Aitkin", "Anoka", "Becker", "Beltrami", "Benton", 
               "Big Stone", "Blue Earth", "Brown", "Carlton", "Carver", 
               "Cass", "Chippewa", "Chisago", "Clay", "Clearwater", "Cook", 
               "Cottonwood", "Crow Wing", "Dakota", "Dodge", "Douglas", 
               "Faribault", "Fillmore", "Freeborn", "Goodhue", "Grant", 
               "Hennepin", "Houston", "Hubbard", "Isanti", "Itasca", "Jackson", 
               "Kanabec", "Kandiyohi", "Kittson", "Koochiching", "Lac Qui Parle", 
               "Lake", "Lake of the Woods", "Le Sueur", "Lincoln", "Lyon", 
               "Mahnomen", "Marshall", "Martin", "McLeod", "Meeker", "Mille Lacs", 
               "Morrison", "Mower", "Murray", "Nicollet", "Nobles", "Norman", 
               "Olmsted", "Otter Tail", "Pennington", "Pine", "Pipestone", 
               "Polk", "Pope", "Ramsey", "Red Lake", "Redwood", "Renville", 
               "Rice", "Rock", "Roseau", "Scott", "Sherburne", "Sibley", 
               "St. Louis", "Stearns", "Steele", "Stevens", "Swift", "Todd", 
               "Traverse", "Wabasha", "Wadena", "Waseca", "Washington", 
               "Watonwan", "Wilkin", "Winona", "Wright", "Yellow Medicine"))

  target <- filter(xlate_df, tolower(county) == tolower(county_name))

  if (nrow(target) == 1) {
    res <- GET("http://maps2.dnr.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/lakefinder_json.cgi",
               query=list(county=target$id))
    jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res, as="parsed"))
  } else {
    message("County not found")
  }

}

get_lake_metadata("Anoka")
get_lake_metadata("Steele")
```

Comment: Progress!! Thank you hrbrmstr!!  Is it too much to ask how I then store the lake IDs to then search their individual pages for the table of fish count? Parsing the website code to extract that table is still killing me.

Comment: Sorry I will be more clear.  The code is working but when I store a county data using that function the data format is overwhelming.  For the length by species data table, how do I tell which column that is under? I am assuming it is storing data as an array, but do not know how to tell.